# default and maximun values allowed for maxerror in amazon s3 copy command

Tags: amazon-s3, copy, command, manifest

I was trying to use s3 copy command in my project.
In my scenario, there are chances for getting a lot of errors.

Here is sample snippet which I found in doc.
Doc link: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html

> copy event from 's3://mybucket/data/allevents_pipe.txt'   iam_role
>   'arn:aws:iam::0123456789012:role/MyRedshiftRole'   removequotes 
>   emptyasnull  blanksasnull  **maxerror** 5  delimiter '|' timeformat
>   'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS' manifest;

I was trying to figure out the maximum and default values for maxerror. I read s3 docs but I couldn't find anything about this.

can anyone please let me know the same?

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always set parameters to dataload operations in copy commands. In your case you can set MAXERROR paraameter to maximum limit it supports(i.e.,  100000). Here is the redshift documentation for the same https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/copy-parameters-data-load.html#copy-maxerror .

Comment: Thanks, @venu 
I was searching this for a long time.